# Will adding a Age Disclaimer landing page to a site make it less search engine optimised?

Tags: seo, html, web-development

I need to add an age disclaimer landing page for an adults only website but am worried that it will make the site less search engine optimised.

The page will have a button (<18) which will redirect away from the site and one (18+) that will direct to the about page of the site.

This will be an independant landing page for the site, not an overlay as there is already a pop-up for something elsr on the index page of the site

Will this affect optimisation?